# RegEx to create AWS Athena Table (RegexSerDe)

Tags: regex, hiveql, amazon-athena, hiveddl, regexserde

I am trying to create AWS Athena table based on the logs stored in S3. I intend to use RegEx to create the table but I could not find RegEx which will work for me

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `dev_logs`(
  `date_time` string COMMENT '', 
  `type` string COMMENT '', 
  `request_id` string COMMENT '', 
  `body` string COMMENT '', 
  `exception` string COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'input.regex'='\\[([^ ]* +[^ ]*)\\] \\[([^ ]*)\\] ([^ ]*) \\[([^ ]* +[^ ]*)\\] (\\*)'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://dev/logs'
```

The logs are in this format

```
[2020-05-04 10:26:56.393] [INFO] [123] [Building host...] []
[2020-05-04 10:27:01.623] [INFO] [] [Starting Service checks...] [exception details]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is

```
'\\[(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d*)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\].*?$'
```

In Hive you can easily debug it using regexp_replace:

```
select regexp_replace('[2020-05-04 10:26:56.393] [INFO] [123] [Building host...] []',
                      '\\[(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d*)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\].*?$',
                     '$1, $2, $3, $4, $5')
```

Result

2020-05-04 10:26:56.393, INFO, 123, Building host...,

Comment: The body field is multiline. How to fetch all the content

Comment: @Moin read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17935200/2700344